# I'm unable to enumerate an NSAttributed Text in Swift 3

Tags: ios, swift, nsattributedstring, enumerate

I'm unable to get this to compile correctly in swift 3. I'm running into the issue of

[image]

Actual code here. i'm not sure why it is asking for an extra , in the code

```
 data2 = items.data(using: .utf8)
            attrString = NSAttributedString(htmlData:data2!,options:[DTDefaultFontSize:13.0,DTDefaultFontFamily:"Verdana",DTDefaultFirstLineHeadIndent:5.0],documentAttributes:nil)
            print(attrString)

            attrString?.enumerateAttribute(NSAttachmentAttributeName , in: NSMakeRange(0, (attrString?.length)!), options: 0, using:^(id value,NSRange range,BOOL *test){
                if(value){
                    print(value)
                }
                })
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must have copied an `Objective-C` example without converting it fully to `swift`. Things like the block syntax and the **if(value)** are valid `Objective-C` but not valid `swift`. The following code works correctly in a `Swift-playground`:

```
let attrString = NSAttributedString(string: "test", attributes: [NSForegroundColorAttributeName : UIColor.red, NSUnderlineColorAttributeName : UIColor.green])
attrString.enumerateAttribute(NSForegroundColorAttributeName , in: NSMakeRange(0, attrString.length), options: [.longestEffectiveRangeNotRequired]) { value, range, isStop in
    if let value = value {
        print(value)
    }
}
```

Comment: Very frustrating that the autocomplete in xCode can't show that.

Comment: I would just like to add that for longer textViews then this is incredibly slow. This can take up to 7 seconds to run this on a modern iPhone XR with a textView that contains 3598 words, and no _excessive_ formatting.